# When using “azure_rm_deployment” the resourcegroups are creating on specific location “us west”?

Tags: azure, ansible

When using "azure_rm_deployment" the resourcegroup only creating in us west location. How could i create it in any other location. Also when trying to create resources inside that resource group created in central india getting error Resource group create_or_update failed with status code: 409 and message: Invalid resource group location 'westus'. The Resource group already exists in location 'centralindia'."}

Here is my code

```
- name: Create Azure Deploy
  azure_rm_deployment:
    state: present
    resource_group_name: "myresources"
    parameters:
       location:
          value: Central India
    template:
      $schema: "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#"
      contentVersion: "1.0.0.0"
      location: "[variables('location')]"
      deployment-name: "mypx"
      resources:
        - type: "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
          apiVersion: "2015-05-01-preview"
          name: "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]"
          location: "[parameters('location')]"
          properties:
            addressSpace:
              addressPrefixes:
                - "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
            subnets:
              - name: "[variables('subnetName')]"
                properties:
                  addressPrefix: "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
```

Answer (score 2):

409 refers to Conflict. It means that the resource Group that you are trying to create already exists. Choose a Unique name for the resource Group.
If you do not see it in portal, use Management APIs to confirm. Sometimes, portal takes a while to sync.
 Also, which tool are you deploying from? Does it have any option of setting defaults. It is possible that default location is set up as US west. If you can share the Json that is generated, it may provide more clues into what might be going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

To create the resource group in a location you choose, you have to use the `location` parameters, not the `parameters` parameter, see the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/azure_rm_deployment_module.html).

So this would give:

```
- name: Create Azure Deploy
  azure_rm_deployment:
    state: present
    resource_group_name: "myresources"
    location: the-desired-location
```

instead of

```
- name: Create Azure Deploy
  azure_rm_deployment:
    state: present
    resource_group_name: "myresources"
    parameters:
       location:
          value: Central India
```

Comment: Does that answer the whole question?